# How to design enter button functionality in virtual keyboard?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I have some `QLineEdit` widgets in my program. I connected their `returnPressed` signal to different functions. I also have a virtual keyboard. When one of these `QLineEdit` widgets are under focus and I press enter in my virtual keyboard how can I run the function for that input?

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QLineEdit, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
import sys


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.resize(400, 200)
        self.inputA = QLineEdit('inputA', self)
        self.inputB = QLineEdit('inputB', self)
        self.inputA.returnPressed.connect(self.funcInputA)
        self.inputB.returnPressed.connect(self.funcInputB)
        self.inputB.move(150, 0)
        self.btnEnter = QPushButton('Enter', self)
        self.btnEnter.move(0, 100)
        self.btnEnter.clicked.connect(self.enter)
        self.btnEnter.setFocusPolicy(Qt.NoFocus)

    
    def funcInputA(self):
        print('inputA')

    def funcInputB(self):
        print('inputB')

    def enter(self):
        widget = QApplication.focusWidget()
        print(widget.text())


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
win = MainWindow()
win.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: With that "virtual keyboard" are you referring to that "Enter" button?

Comment: @musicamante Yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most events can be *synthesized*, including key events, and relayed to target widgets.

Note that, for consistency, you should always send both key press and release events for each "virtual" key press.

```py
    def enter(self):
        widget = QApplication.focusWidget()
        if widget is not None:
            modifiers = Qt.KeyboardModifiers()
            for evType in (QEvent.KeyPress, QEvent.KeyRelease):
                event = QKeyEvent(evType, Qt.Key_Return, modifiers)
                QApplication.postEvent(widget, event)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you please show me how can I send key press and release events specifically for this virtual enter button?

Comment: @Mohammad what do you mean? That's *exactly* what my code does.

Comment: I'm sorry. By "sending both key press and release event" I thought I should override these events, whereas this is actually done in this code.